# Dynamic class value for store like array in android?

Tags: java, android

hii i want to pass the value dynamically using for loop in class function for holding the data so how can i do this in java

when i implement this code this put only one image i want pass the value up to for loop

here i put my code check it

> CustomData.java

```
/** This is just a simple class for holding data that is used to render our custom view */
public class CustomData 
{ 
    private String mText;

    public CustomData(String text) {

        mText = text;
    }
    public String getText() 
    {
        return mText;
    }

}
```

> Activityclass.java

```
 public class ListMobileActivity extends Activity { 

Button btnradio;
ListView lv;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menulist = new    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

ArrayList<String> test= new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> custom;
int size=1;
 public CustomData[] mCustomData= new CustomData[size];


 private HorizontalListView myhorizontalview;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listmobileactivity);

    myhorizontalview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.myhorizontalview);

    new MenuAsynctask().execute("");

    myhorizontalview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
        {




        }


    });

}



public class MenuAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>
{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) 
    {

        try 
        {
                JsonParser jparser = new JsonParser();

                String url="http://www.weboffice.co.at/webservices/services.php?method=content";


                String data=jparser.getdata(url);
                //Log.e("data","--->"+data);

                JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(data);

                JSONArray jcontent=jobject.getJSONArray("CONTENT");
                size=jcontent.length();
                for(int i=0;i<jcontent.length();i++)
                {

                    String title=jcontent.getJSONObject(i).get("title").toString();
                    String come=jcontent.getJSONObject(i).get("short").toString();
                    String image=jcontent.getJSONObject(i).get("image").toString();

                    mCustomData[i] = new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"); 
                }


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return menulist;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) 
    {

        Log.e("data","--->"+mCustomData.toString());

        CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(ListMobileActivity.this, mCustomData);
        myhorizontalview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

}

```
i want to create array like this how to achieve this

public CustomData[] mCustomData = new CustomData[] {
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
        };
```

Comment: You are passing same image String image="http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"; in loop

Comment: And write mCustomData= new CustomData(image);

Comment: this is just for demo after that image is comming from webservice and put in this customdata class

Comment: `mCustomData= new CustomData { new CustomData(image)}; //===> bad way mCustomData= new CustomData(image); //===> Good way`

Comment: but this gives me error change type mCustomdata to CustomData

Comment: I just updated the answer see that

Comment: public CustomData[] mCustomData = new CustomData[] {
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg")};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`CustomData mCustomData= new CustomData(image);`

to initialize and you should store this  in a `ArrayList` to access the data later

**UPDATE**

```
CustomData[] dataList = new CustomData[SIZE]; 

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    dataList[i] = new CustomData(image); 
}
```

If you dont have fixed size then use

```
ArrayList<CustomData> dataList = new ArrayList<CustomData>();
dataList.add(new CustomData(image));

and to retrieve use

dataList.get(position);
```

Try

```
 public CustomData[] mCustomData; // Remove initialization
```

Within `MenuAsynctask` `doInBackground`

```
mCustomData = new CustomData[jcontent.length()];
```

it will work

Comment: public CustomData[] mCustomData = new CustomData[] {
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg"),
                new CustomData("http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg")}; i want to fill image like this how to achieve this

Comment: still display only one image  after that 02-15 14:48:59.630: W/System.err(618): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Thats because you exceed the size, can you post the code that you tried, You have alternatives like arrayList i just posted a sample

Comment: Your array size is 1 thats why its causing the problem

Comment: but i want to assign that size dynamically how can i do this